# Cmake Debug flag condition for one build with multiple projects

Tags: c, cmake

I need help in compiling my projects with debug flag.

I have compiled with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..` in build folder.

I am able to run the binary after the compilation. However, the Debug flag is not being turned on. I am sort of stuck at this point. Any kind soul is willing to give a kind advise or direction on this?

My build tree is as such:

```
project
|------ CMakeLists.txt (The main Cmake)
|------ ProjectA
|          |----- src
                   |.c files
|          |----- include
                   |.h files
|          |----- CMakeList.txt
|------ ProjectB
|          |----- src
                   |.c files
|          |----- include
                   |.h files
|          |----- CMakeList.txt
| 
|------ build
|         |-----  ...
|------ bin
|        |---- executables
```

I have set my cmake flag in the project A and B as such:

```
#cmake output directory
...
#compiler
...
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "... -DDEBUG ...")
#Linking
...
#add executables
...
```

My top level CMakeLists.text is such:

```
project(..)
...

add_subdirectory(ProjectA)
add_subdirectory(ProjectB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main CMakeLists.txt add below line

```
## Configure debug flag to enable debug log

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall")
```

Generate Makefile:

```
cmake ..... -DCMAKE_ARCH="x86_64" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

Comment: let me try to understand what you are suggesting here.
what does this line actually do?
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} -DMSGLOG")

Comment: it will make sure set -DDEBUG to cflag and build Debug version